# C# MVC Dropdownlist using IEnumerable Visualizer

Tags: c#, json, drop-down-menu, viewbag, selectlist

I have column `String` in IEnumerable Visualizer. List contains elements downloaded from an API (THB, USD, EUR etc...). How can I create a dropdownlist in the view for this column?

I was trying:

```
@Html.Dropdownlist("String", ViewBag.currenciesList as SelectList, "Select Value", new {@class ="form-control"});
```

And it does not work - it shows exception in "String".

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertCurrencies(decimal amount, string currencyCode, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    var nbpApiUrl = RatesExchangeServices.tableAUrl;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Exchange rate from currency :
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(nbpApiUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage getdataFrom = client.GetAsync(nbpApiUrl).Result;
        string responseFrom = getdataFrom.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (!getdataFrom.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception("Valid connection with Api");
        }

        dynamic jsonResponseFrom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFrom);

        var currenciestList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var rate in jsonResponseFrom[0].rates)
        {
            currenciestList.Add(rate.code.ToString());
        }

        ViewBag.currenciesList = new SelectList(currenciestList);
    }
}
```

I need to create a dropdownlist.

[currenciesList visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BEkL.png)

[responseFrom visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IOxz.png)

JSON responseFrom :

```
[{"table":"A","no":"055/A/NBP/2023","effectiveDate":"2023-03-20","rates":[{"currency":"bat (Tajlandia)","code":"THB","mid":0.1294},{"currency":"dolar amerykański","code":"USD","mid":4.4130},{"currency":"dolar australijski","code":"AUD","mid":2.9466},{"currency":"dolar Hongkongu","code":"HKD","mid":0.5626},{"currency":"dolar kanadyjski","code":"CAD","mid":3.2168},{"currency":"dolar nowozelandzki","code":"NZD","mid":2.7521},{"currency":"dolar singapurski","code":"SGD","mid":3.2890},{"currency":"euro","code":"EUR","mid":4.7109},{"currency":"forint (Węgry)","code":"HUF","mid":0.011809},{"currency":"frank szwajcarski","code":"CHF","mid":4.7477},{"currency":"funt szterling","code":"GBP","mid":5.3808},{"currency":"hrywna (Ukraina)","code":"UAH","mid":0.1258},{"currency":"jen (Japonia)","code":"JPY","mid":0.033634},{"currency":"korona czeska","code":"CZK","mid":0.1963},{"currency":"korona duńska","code":"DKK","mid":0.6328},{"currency":"korona islandzka","code":"ISK","mid":0.031469},{"currency":"korona norweska","code":"NOK","mid":0.4119},{"currency":"korona szwedzka","code":"SEK","mid":0.4205},{"currency":"lej rumuński","code":"RON","mid":0.9572},{"currency":"lew (Bułgaria)","code":"BGN","mid":2.4086},{"currency":"lira turecka","code":"TRY","mid":0.2322},{"currency":"nowy izraelski szekel","code":"ILS","mid":1.2003},{"currency":"peso chilijskie","code":"CLP","mid":0.005336},{"currency":"peso filipińskie","code":"PHP","mid":0.0809},{"currency":"peso meksykańskie","code":"MXN","mid":0.2321},{"currency":"rand (Republika Południowej Afryki)","code":"ZAR","mid":0.2384},{"currency":"real (Brazylia)","code":"BRL","mid":0.8365},{"currency":"ringgit (Malezja)","code":"MYR","mid":0.9837},{"currency":"rupia indonezyjska","code":"IDR","mid":0.00028731},{"currency":"rupia indyjska","code":"INR","mid":0.053404},{"currency":"won południowokoreański","code":"KRW","mid":0.003367},{"currency":"yuan renminbi (Chiny)","code":"CNY","mid":0.6408},{"currency":"SDR (MFW)","code":"XDR","mid":5.9184}]}]
```

Comment: You have to show us a json string responseFrom if you really need some help

Comment: edited, added a screen

Comment: No , images are prohibited here. Pls add as a text a  json string from string responseFrom = getdataFrom.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: actually i just do not have idea how can i create a dropdownlist for elements from currenciesList visualizer.

Comment: added as a text

Comment: The first parameter in the helper is the selected model property bound to dropdown, therefore it cannot be a keyword like "String."

Answer (score 0):

try this code to create a select list

```
string json = getdataFrom.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

 var rates = ((JArray)JArray.Parse(json)[0]["rates"])
                .Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = (string)v["code"], Value = v["code"].ToString() });

 ViewBag.currenciesList = rates;
```

and view

```
 <select  asp-for="... your field" asp-items="ViewBag.currenciesList"></select>
```

and check _ViewImports.cshtml file , since you use net.core  it should contain

```
@using TestCore.WebApp
@using TestCore.WebApp.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: You have to post your view. And I don't know what net version are you using

Comment: using .Net Core 3.1, and actually i do not have view because i just need to get to know how can i create dropdownlist.

Comment: I created this select list as u wrote above, but it is empty. It does not shows rates elements.

Comment: @JJablonski How you can create dropdownlist control without view?  Just remove asp-for if  you don't have a model. All my code is tested, if you don't see anything it means you poster a wrong json string

Comment: Okay, i understood. It was showing me values but after entering the value in input. I need to change it and it will work as I want. Thank you Serge !